# What does "single allocation" mean for boost::make_shared

Tags: c++, boost, shared-ptr, smart-pointers, make-shared

In the boost doc of [make_shared](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/smart_ptr/make_shared.html), it says:

> Besides convenience and style, such a function is also exception safe and considerably 
>   faster because it can use **a single allocation for both the object and its corresponding 
>   control block**, eliminating a significant portion of shared_ptr's construction overhead.

I don't understand the meaning of "single allocation", what does it mean?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

An "allocation" means a block of memory obtained from a call to an allocator.

Usually, creating a `shared_ptr` with the pointer constructor allocates memory for a "control block", which holds the reference count and the deleter. Copies of that `shared_ptr` all refer to the same control block, so that they share the reference count. Hence there are two allocations in total - the object itself and the control block created by `shared_ptr`.

If you create the object and `shared_ptr` together with `make_shared`, then only one allocation is made. You can think of this as a single struct with two members:

1. The object which is being managed
2. The control block.

Comment: The limit in flexibility is that you don't get to choose the allocator for `make_shared`: It's always `std::allocator`. By the way, how do they manage that `T*` is still always at the top of the data structure?

Answer (score 4):

The `shared_ptr` needs to allocate space for the reference count. This means that you will dynamically create your object (one allocation) and pass it to the `shared_ptr` that will in turn allocate the count (second allocation). `make_shared` performs a single allocation of a big enough size and then constructs in place both the count and the object.